# Language-String parsing in Views

Tags: php, parsing, internationalization, memcached

I'm faced with the following problem, I have this view (simplified):

```
<div>
    <?php echo $memcached->get('hello'); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $memcached->get('world'); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $memcached->get('apple'); ?>
</div>
```

`$memcached` is a Memcached-DAO that retrieves the language strings from a caching server.

I want to optimize this to make a multi-get instead of retrieving each string separately. (Also only getting the ones I need and in the right place - without defining a list of strings to use in before)

How could I do this in PHP5?

Comment: Your question is more than a year old. Did you found a solution to your problem? Reading it today, it is not clear to me if you are looking for these distinct three entries by their keys or if you want to get all entries in form of an array without specifying keys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the php memcache?

```
array Memcache::get ( array $keys [, array &$flags ] )
```

-> http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php

Comment: `$memcached` is a Memcached-DAO [...] naturally based on the only memcached implementation available for PHP. Where's your answer?

Comment: With get ( array ) you perform a multi-get and get a array of values.